# Rabbitmq Custom Configfile and custom port

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed erlang otp and rabbitmq server on a machine.

I have created an environment variable 'RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE' with value "C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.3.1\etc\rabbitmq" (it appends .config automatically"

I went to services.msc and restarted rabbitmq service.

Still the configuration is not detected by server.

The log files says, "C:\WINDOWS
config file(s) : c:/Program Files (x86)/RabbitMQ Server/rabbitmq_server-3.3.1/etc/rabbitmq.config (not found)"

while on the given path the config file exist.

Content of config file is copied from rabbitmq.config.example file

Also if i want to change port from 5672 to custom port what configuration should i add to rabbitmq.config.

Do let me know if any other info is required

Comment: Does default config location on windows (%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\) works for you?

Comment: @zaq178miami: I will try it and let you know..

Comment: @zaq178miami: Nope even %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ is not working. :(